# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'str' Python 3.6.2

Tags: python, typeerror

I have got a leader board being imported from a .csv file *(comma deliminated)* and it is being put into the list `leaderboard` in the format `[["49","Joe","29/9/18"],["89",Sam","13/4/17"]]`. I have multiple lists in the nested array. I am sorting the `leaderboard` with:

```
leaderboard = sorted(leaderboard, reverse = True)
```

then this brings back the **Type Error**. Sorting the list in order of the scores for each player in position [0].

How do I get around the type error so I can use my script further?

Comment: For the given data it works. But based on the error, the sublists do not only contain strings, but a list as well.

Comment: Once the missing quotation mark is fixed, there is no type error in what you've shown us. Therefore the error is in something you haven't shown us. Please show us the code that exhibits the error. We need a [mcve]. For example, I get the error you describe if `leaderboard` is set to `[["49","Joe","29/9/18"],["89","Sam","13/4/17"],"foo"]`

Comment: Thank you, I have had a section of code with appended the str `"N/A"` due to a function in the code to send the players last score for the game into the leaderboard. This was the str value which was producing the error and I hae placed this into an if statement for my script to stop it being added the the list `leaderboard`

Comment: Alternatively, you could have appended the list `["N/A"]`, instead of the str `"NA"` to the leaderboard, rather than avoiding it.  Depends on the usage in the rest of the application.